# Use Regular Expressions in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, regex, hibernate, jpa

I'm using the JPA CriteriaBuilder to select entities of type `MyEntity` from a MySQL db as follows:

```
String regExp = "(abc|def)"
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery( MyEntity.class );
root = query.from( MyEntity.class );
predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add( cb.like( root.<String>get( "name" ), regExp ) );
```

Thus, the query result should contain any entity where the `name` value matches the given regExp. But the result list is always empty.
Changing the regExp to `/(abc|def)/g` has no effect, neither does adding the wildcard `%`

How to make the pattern matching work?

Alternatively: How can I use native MySQL REGEXP together with the CriteriaBuilder?

Answer (score 9):

Pattern matching in JPA queries is limited only to

- `_` - any character
- `%` - any string

`REGEXP` has operator syntax in MySQL (`SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A'`) so it cannot be used with `CriteriaBuilder.function()` API. I'm afraid the best is to run native SQL query.

If you are using Hibernate you have one more option. You can [wrap `REGEXP` operator in `SQLFunctionTemplate`, extend hibernate dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17702545/3796586) and run with `CriteriaBuilder.function()`.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this recently and used the first post to implement the hibernate mysql function option.

To help save some time for others this is what I did:

set up the function in your custom dialect file in hibernate:

```
public class MySQLDialect extends Dialect {

   public MySQLDialect() {
      super();
      ...
      registerFunction("regexp", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 REGEXP ?2"));
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

then 
within the criteria builder section:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = ...;    

Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]\\|[0-9]+");

Expression<String> patternExpression = builder.<String>literal(regexPattern.pattern());

Path<String> path = ... ;// regex comparison column

// regexp comes from the name of the regex function 
// defined in the Mysql Dialect file above
Predicate theRegexPredicate = builder.equal(builder.function("regexp", Integer.class, path, patternExpression), 1);
```

Then use theRegexPredicate to construct the where clause in your CriteriaBuilder query.

Comment: I tried just what you said but it doesn't return anything. Can you have a look at ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601147/jpa-criteria-api-with-regexp-like-function, maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this snippet will help. We had to exclude characters in a search, and we using Oracle. CriteriaBuilder (at least as of 2.1) will let you call a function.

```
private static final Pattern UNDESIRABLES = Pattern.compile("[(){},.;!?<>%_-]");
private static final String UNDESIRABLE_REPLACEMENT = "";
...
```

In the search method, create a Predicate to use in your where clause:

```
Expression<String> undesirables = cb.literal(UNDESIRABLES.toString());
Expression<String> replaceWith = cb.literal(UNDESIRABLE_REPLACEMENT);
Expression<String> regExp = cb.function("REGEXP_REPLACE", String.class, client.get(Client_.companyName),
    undesirables, replaceWith);
Predicate companyNameMatch = cb.equal(cb.trim(cb.lower(regExp)), removeUndesireables(name).trim());
...
```

And create a method for the right hand comapare that uses the same values as the left:

```
private String removeUndesireables(String name) {
    return UNDESIRABLES.matcher(name).replaceAll(UNDESIRABLE_REPLACEMENT).toLowerCase();
}
```