# not consider spaces in spring data query findByTitreContaining

Tags: spring-data

I m using Spring Data to search for a String like this :

```
My interface repository :
public interface AnnonceDao extends   JpaRepository<Annonce, Integer> {
    Page<Annonce> findByTitreContaining(String titre,Pageable page);
}
```

When I search for String like : **ben  [2 spaces]    boudj** it doesen t give a result  even there are **ben [1 space] boudj**

I look for something to not consider spaces : I mean one or two spaces or more are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work JPA would need support for regular expressions which it hasn't.

Some databases do have support for them, for example, MySQL seems to support them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996378/66686

Once you have a native query you can integrate it in your Spring Data Repository with a `@Query` annotation.